# displaying lines read from word document not accurate

Tags: string, file, vb6, ms-word, programming-languages

```
Sub test()
    Dim TextLine As String
    Open "E:\PROJECTS\CLIENTS\VINCI\MACROS\vn_macro\test.docx" For Input As #1

    Do While Not EOF(1)    ' Loop until end of file.
        Line Input #1, TextLine    ' Read line into variable.
        MsgBox TextLine    ' Print to the Immediate window.
    Loop
    Close #1    ' Close file.
End Sub
```

inside the same file I am reading from, as a macro.

In the word document I have these simple strings : love computer science each separated by new line.

When I try to run the code, the msgbox function displays strange strings for each of my simple strings, and one extra one. the code finds 4 strings instead of 3.

What I basically want to do, is read the current opened document line by line, or 10 lines by 10 lines if you can spare some extra time, and insert the exact line(s) shown in the document into a temp string.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to use Word Automation. You cannot access the file as a text file as Word contains many meta tags and other formatting.

Have a look at [Interop Class Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and [this for an example](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/dotnet/soa/Easily-utilise-Microsoft-Word-functionality-in-your-NET-application/0,339028399,339198903,00.htm).

EDIT: Sorry this is for .NET. There is Word Automation for VB6 as well, I remember doing this sort of stuff back in the day. You will need to add the reference for this.

NEW EDIT: Actually I found a pretty good site for Word Automation with VB6. [Click this link](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/visual-basic-4-5-6/tutorials/51307). Additionally, you may also find [this](http://www.tomorrowssolutionsllc.com/Materials/AutomatingWord.html) useful.